# JScrollPane messing with size

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I am trying to add a JScrollPane to a JList, however it messes up the size when i do it as shown in the picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvkT9.jpg

If the list is empty it will be large like the one on the right, however if i add something to it it will then shrink to the size as the one on the right, setting max size or prefered size has no affect on it.

This is annoying and i would like it to always look like the one on the left regardless of whether it is empty or not.  Here is the code i am using but do to the complexity of the project it would be hard to provide a working example.

```
private JPanel setUpRight(){
    //right.setLayout(new BoxLayout(right,BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    right.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(
            2, //top
            10,     //left
            2, //bottom
            10));   //right
    JPanel localCenter = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel localBottom = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    saves.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    saves.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
    saves.setDragEnabled(true);
    saves.setTransferHandler(new FromTransferHandler());
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(saves,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);


    configs.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    configs.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
    configs.setDragEnabled(true);
    configs.setTransferHandler(new FromTransferHandler1());
    JScrollPane scroll1 = new JScrollPane(configs,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    localCenter.add(new JLabel("List of saved macros"),BorderLayout.NORTH);
    localCenter.add(scroll,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    localCenter.add(new JButton("Delete"),BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    localBottom.add(new JLabel("List of saved configs"),BorderLayout.NORTH);
    localBottom.add(scroll1,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    right.add(localCenter);

    right.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(left.getHeight(), 10)));
    JSeparator separate = new JSeparator(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL);
    Dimension d = separate.getPreferredSize();
    d.width = separate.getMaximumSize().width;
    separate.setMaximumSize( d );

    right.add(separate,BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS);
    right.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(left.getHeight(), 10)));

    right.add(localBottom);
    return right;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't appear to be calling the most important methods on your JList objects for having them size the JScrollPane's viewport correctly: `setVisibleRowCount(int rowCount)` and `setPrototypeCellValue(T value)`. The one helps the JList tell the JScrollPane its vertical viewport size and the 2nd method helps the JList tell its holding JScrollPane the preferred horizontal viewport size.

Please check the [JList API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) for the details.

e.g.,

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JListExample extends JPanel {
    public JListExample() {
        String[] listData = { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "One", "Two", "Three",
                "Four", "Five", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "One", "Two", "Three",
                "Four", "Five", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "One", "Two", "Three",
                "Four", "Five", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "One", "Two", "Three",
                "Four", "Five", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "One", "Two", "Three",
                "Four", "Five", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "One", "Two", "Three",
                "Four", "Five", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "One", "Two", "Three",
                "Four", "Five" };
        JList<String> myList = new JList<>(listData);

        myList.setVisibleRowCount(10);
        myList.setPrototypeCellValue("abcdefghijklm");
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(myList);
        add(scrollPane);

    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JListExample mainPanel = new JListExample();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("E.G.");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, i tried setVisibleRowCount(int rowCount) and it didnt affect width, but then i did setPrototypeCellValue(T value) and i just used the value from the javadocs which was .setPrototypeCellValue("Index 1234567890"); and it worked, but what exactly does "Index 1234567890" mean, how is this function working?

Comment: @EricNawrocki: I'm not sure why you'd think that setVisibleRowCount would set the width, just the name of the method alone tells you exactly what it does, right? As for the meaning of "Index 1234567890". It means *nothing*. It's simply a nonsense String that tells the JList that it should be wide enough to display a String of that size. It also sets the height of each row -- but then the JList API tells you all this. Please do make it a habit to explore the API since doing so will free you.